# Schedule a subscription on gravity form, stripe add-on

Tags: customization

I manage a non-profit website [here](https://www.sevenspikesrelief.org.uk/)
I need to create a gravity form that enables donors to schedule their donations from a certain date to a certain date.
Donor can select (from that range) the days on which they want to donate, or they might select all of them.
Please see this [example](https://www.islamic-relief.org.uk/mytennights/)
is that possible with gravity form and stripe addon?

Or, if you can suggest any other solution not necessary gravity form.

Comment: Since this is specific to Gravity Forms, please contact them directly for help. Their documentation may also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with Gravity Forms Stripe Add-On - https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/stripe/

Follow the Gravity Forms tutorial for setting up a subscription in Stripe - https://docs.gravityforms.com/stripe-add-on/